# Annotation chart: Filter the data does not work on chart?

Tags: charts, annotations, google-visualization

I would like to have a question about Google Annotation Chart on the Option Filter Data (displayAnnotationsFilter)

My question: Why the Filter do not support data on the graph? (Or will it be support in the future) 
*When I use text to filter the data, it 's only fitter the data on the right but not on the graph. May be this is a little bit confuse. So I 've just wonder that would it be better if we can filter both the annotation data and the graph?

Google Annotation option

```
...
displayAnnotations: true, // show annotation
vAxis: {direction: 1},
displayAnnotationsFilter: true // add filter 
...
```

[image]

Document: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart

Testcode
https://jsfiddle.net/lecaoquochung/dsmgL9wj/2/

Comment: The filter here is primarily used to _find_ annotations, when there are several to look thru. If you would like to filter everything, you could use a [Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboardobject) and [String Filter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#stringfilter) on the annotation column...

Comment: This is a little bit different: pre-defined value and free-style search input filter. However, thank you very much and I will test it out.